# Python keyword same as xml tag

Tags: python, xml, keyword

I am trying to do some web **scraping** and I came across this problem: I wanna take a tag that's called `<name>` but name is also a keyword in python so when I try to take that tag with the code below:

```
entries_map = []
for entry in entries:
    entry_title = entry.title.text
    entry_author = entry.name
    entries_map.append(entry_author)
    entries_map.append(entry_title)

print(entries_map)
```

I get this: ['entry', "Some title I scraped", 'entry', "Some title I scraped", ...]

So how can I take that tag?

Comment: What are you using to parse the XML?

Comment: I am using beautiful soup library and lxml for parse method

Comment: What output are you expecting to get?

Comment: Not sure if that will solve your problem, but in beautiful soup you would sometimes have to use an underscore to use Python keywords (e.g., `class_` to refer to `class`), so you could try `name_`? If it doesn't work, you can always use `getattr(entry, 'name')`.

Comment: First of [here](https://www.vox.com/rss/index.xml) is the feed i am trying to scrap and I want to get the text that is the authors name.

Comment: @fsimonjetz name_ does not help and ```getattr(entry, 'name')``` gives the same output

Comment: note that `name` is not a reserved word in python, though it has a special meaning in the lxml library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.find()` method to search for a child element with a specific tag.

```
    entry_author = entry.find('name').text
```